# Other liquids for collecting gas by displacement method for SO2

Tags: solubility

I am looking for a low cost method of quantifying gases evolved from a reaction. The gas mixture is expected to have $\ce{H2}$, $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ but likely others too. I am considering using a syringe but am somewhat apprehensive about syringe friction and back pressure distorting volume. Commonly used water displacement method obviously would not work due to soluble and reactive gases in the mix. Is there an inert replacement for water for this method to work with $\ce{SO2}$?

I thought about allowing the $\ce{SO2}$ to react in the water and then calculating the amount through pH change. However, $\ce{CO2}$ is also soluble (and others too perhaps)

Without access to chromatographic or other elemental analysis equipment, is there a primitive way of just measuring the volume of this gas mixture?

Comment: I guess you could you easily use many typical solvents instead of water

Comment: Thanks @Mithoron. Is it reasonable to assume that the likes of toluene or acetone will not react with carbon dioxide uncatalysed and at atmospheric conditions? Same for SO2?

Comment: Non-volatile, non-polar solvent would be best, I guess.